# 1st – 2nd Cousin 395 cM | 6% shared DNA Father's side

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, 23andme, half-first-cousins

I've connected with a cousin on ancestry.com and 23andme and dna doesn't lie he is my cousin.  however we cannot find out who our common ancestor is.  1st – 2nd Cousin
395 cM | 6% shared DNA
Father's side.

Possible DNA relationships

This table shows the percentage of the time people sharing 395 cM have the following relationships:

```
Percent Relationship
83% 
1st cousin 1x removed
Half 1st cousin
2nd great-grandparent
2nd great-grandchild
Great-grandaunt/granduncle
Great-grandniece/grandnephew
Half grandaunt/granduncle
Half grandniece/grandnephew
See less
14% 
2nd cousin
1st cousin 2x removed
Half 1st cousin 1x removed
Half great-grandaunt/granduncle
Half great-grandniece/grandnephew
1%  
1st cousin
```

i think he is a half 1st cousin 1x removed. i know the relationship is coming from my paternal side.  but i'm unsure if it is coming from his father or his mothers side.  i'm thinking it's my paternal grandmothers half siblings child.  care to take a jab at it?

Comment: You should be able to narrow down the possibilities from https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/395 by considering the ages of you and your match, and whatever else you each know of your family relationships.

Comment: The "Shared Matches" can have important clues. However, if your grandparents are slightly related, like mine are, this can cause more confusion.